# BufferedReader proper usage

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I use the following style to read a file with BufferedReader

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my_file"))) {
  ...
  br.close();
} catch( IOException e ) {
  System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
}
```

Things that I want to know:

1- Is `close()` in the right place?

2- Should I put another `try..catch` for `close()?

3- Since I used `new` for `br`, is the enough to call the `close()` or I have to write `br = null` for the GC?

4- `FileReader` has been `new`ed, so should I destroy it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Since you use the [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, you don't need to close the stream explicitely. It is automatically closed in any case. If you wouldn't have used try-with-resource, the `close()` would have been in the wrong place. To make sure your resource is always closed, you need to call close() in the `finally` block
2. If you call close() in the finally block, you need to catch the checked Exception thrown by it, too. If you use try-with-resource (like you did), you are fine
3. All your variables live only in the scope of the try block, so you are safe
4. BufferedReader closes the decorated Reader, so you don't have to close it explicitely

Answer (score 2):

You are using `try-with-resources` statement in you code. In this example, the resource declared in the `try-with-resources` statement is a `BufferedReader`. The declaration statement appears within parentheses immediately after the `try` keyword. The class `BufferedReader`, in `Java SE 7 and later`, implements the interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. Because the `BufferedReader` instance is declared in a `try-with-resource` statement, it will be **closed** regardless of whether the `try` statement completes **normally** or **abruptly**. You can learn more about this statement from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). So, here is modified version:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my_file"))) {
  // your logic

} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. You don't need to explicitly call close on your Reader. Indeed the documentation state:

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

Furthermore your FileReader is Decorated by the BufferedReader and closing BufferedReader should close the FileReader.

Answer (score 0):

1-2- It is better to use close together with a finally or resource block. Otherwise the close will not get called if an Exception occurs before.

3- It is enough to call close(). Setting objects to null does not delete the reference. GC will destroy the objects when there are nor references to the objects anymore. So don't destroy your objects manually.